# Android : How can I find location using just PINCODE?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I am trying to get location using PINCODE/ZIPCODE ex:560001 (Bangalore pincode).I am getting the location when I enter the ADDRESS , STATE & COUNTRY, but unable to get using pincode/zipcode. It displays UNKNOWN address.. **can we find LOCATION using PINCODE ??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a location (latitude, longitude) using any piece of address information but at the cost of accuracy. 
Now obviously you can have a lat long corresponding individually to a 
country, state, city, zip , address, etc and each will be more and more accurate, the more information you use.

Having said that, which GPS app are you using and to do what?

If the task is to find say restaurants, providing pincode should be enough.

but if you want to route from point A to point B , providing destination pincode will be hardly useful it wont pin point your exact location.

> UPDATE

You can find points of interest like restaurants, banks etc, you can use google places api. You can search by just providing the pin code. refer to the following documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearches

Comment: Yup my task is to find petrol bunk or any hotel using pincode . If any way please let me know. Thanks @Shaunak

Comment: But where I am writing zipcode or pincode methods for particular area to find ??